# How to make typescript compatible with dynamically changeable value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the below logic and I want to be able to make a scalable model where I can for example use 10 different bodies with different names to set a modal as for now I have tow the type variable is set Modal function gets the id and and sets it in the context, the issue I am getting is

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'body' ts don't know what type in this case will be how to make it know that the value of type will be same as of type body ? I don't want to use casting since all of this will have no purpose.

```js
// Context API State ********************************************************//
type body = 'preference' | 'split';
SetModal: (body: body) => void;

// Component  ********************************************************//
const setModal = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
      const type = e.currentTarget.id;
      // Try to check the value of type WORKING BUT NOT SCALEABLE
       if (type === 'preference' || type === 'split' ) {
          context.SetModal(type);
      }
};

<Button id='preference' onClick={setModal}>            
Preference
</Button>

<Button id='split'  onClick={setModal}>            
Split
</Button>
```

Comment: You can use generic

Comment: could you please elaborate in code in an answer, my experience with generics is minimal it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that TypeScript can't infer from your code that the `setModal` event handler will only ever be applied to components with an `id` property that is of type `body`.  Since you apply this handler to a generic `Button` component, I'll assume we can't change the `React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>` portion.  This leaves us with the call to `context.SetModal(id)`.  We don't want to just type-cast there because then it's the same as if we had written `SetModal: (body: any) => void`.  But we *can* use "[Type Predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)" to ensure the validity of the call:

```js
const valid_body_type_values = ['preferences', 'split'];
type body = typeof valid_body_type_values[number];
const VALID_BODY_TYPES = new Set(valid_body_type_values);
function assertValidBodyType(key: string): asserts key is body {
  if (!VALID_BODY_TYPES.has(key)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid value for body: ${key}`);
  }
}

// Component  ********************************************************//
const setModal = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    const type = e.currentTarget.id;
    assertValidBodyType(type);
    context.SetModal(type);
};
```

Comment: so generics wont help here at all as someone suggested either an enum ?

Comment: tbh there is still an issue with they type var.

Comment: valid_body_type_values === string[] so there is still no way for ts to know since type infrence is an array of strings.

Comment: I updated the code in the question to code that works your answer sounded promising but for some reason the assert is not working.

Comment: What version of TS are you on?